# "Looking to" vs "Looking for"

Tags: sentence-construction

I wrote the sentence

> **Looking to** develop your skills?

Can I change this sentence into the below?

> **Looking for** **develping** your skills?

or

> **Looking for development** of your skills?

Comment: "Looking for development of your skills**?**" sounds strange, but it is okay. "Looking for skill development?" is more natural. "Looking to develop your skills?" is the most idiomatic way to write this.

Comment: Why would you want to change it from something that makes you sound like you speak English to something that makes you sound like you don't?

Comment: The first one is the best phrase (it is a common phrase used with different subjects) to put in a sentence. You need a subject and a verb. You cannot use the understood subject (you) with your phrase: (you) looking to develop your skills? The correct way is with a verb: "Are you looking to develop your skills?" "Is she looking to develop her skills?" etc. The other two phrases are awkward and use more words than you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only "valid" sentence of the three is the first one -> "Looking to develop your skills?"

I know I'm supposed to "Provide details and share your research", but as a native UK English speaking professional translator and former T&EFL teacher, I find this pretty basic.